# Amplify the output current of an MCP4725 in order to drive multiple sensors

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, amplifier, dac, buffer

I want to connect the signal generated by a MCP4725 digital to analog converter to the heater of five sensors.

The LA6500 works well to amplify the output current mcp4725 for one heater sensor. Can I use the structure of the figure below to amplify the output current of the MCP4725 and the multi-output drive?

[image]

Comment: That will give the same voltage, not current. If that's what you mean, sure. With a one-part "power op amp" like that, also check that it turns off all the way to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/a1c1/0900766b816dece0.pdf) the common mode input voltage is restricted to within 3 volts of the supply rails hence it is highly likely that it is a poor choice for your application when running from a single supply of 6 volts. It also appears that the chip is unlikely to work on a single supply rails as low as 6 volts. The data sheet appears to list a couple of supply voltage options and none are as low as 6 volts: -

- +15 volts and -15 volts
- +5 volts and -15 volts
- +15 volts and - 5volts

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I took 1 to 4.6 volts at the output of the la6500 with a supply voltage of 6 volts.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for using a bipolar power supply?(diagram or partnumber)

Comment: I'd be more inclined to design my own hence no OTS recommendations.